# Java call stored procedure with parameter type of varbinary

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, jpa, stored-procedures

Would like to query does anyone have idea how to call stored procedure with three parameters(first two are varchar and third one is varbinary) in java, I tried to call it through jpa's nativequery

stored procedure calling script from SQL server

```
DECLARE @userSid as VARBINARY(100)
SET @test_id = SUSER_SID('test_account')
select @test_id;

EXEC dbo.testUser 'test','test',@test_id
```

Below is what I tried to execute stored procedure so far from nativequery

```
@Query(value = "{call testUser(:name,:Application,:test_id)}",nativeQuery=true)
    public Object callTestProcedure(@Param("name") String name,@Param("Application") String Application,@Param("test_id") byte[] test_id);
```

Tried to call it as below..

```
callTestProcedure("Truview","TruViewDataHub",Base64.decodeBase64("0x01050000000000051500000011D81D73D36F037181499C550F1A0000"))
```

But this doesn't work, any helps will be appreciated.. thank you

updated.. also tried to convert to HEX as below

```
String hex=String.format("%040x", new BigInteger(1, "0x01050000000000051500000011D81D73D36F037181499C550F1A0000".getBytes("UTF-8")));
callTestProcedure("Truview","TruViewDataHub",hex);
```

which will cause another error "Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to varbinary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query."

Comment: That's a hex string, not a Base64 string.

Comment: @David Browne - Microsoft
Thank you for the answer, but seems to when I use HEX String will shows error :Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to varbinary is not allowed..